# Python, List of parents based on child's attribute

Tags: python, xml

I'm not used to parsing xml in Python and I'm a little stuck on the following.

I have an XML file with a number of locations represented as lat, lon values in node elements.

The type of location is in a "tag" element with "k" and "v" attributes.

```
<root>
    <node id="12345678" lat="50.5" lon="3.0" otherdata="not needed">
        <tag k="this_key" v="value_a"/>
        <tag k="that_key" v="value_b"/>
    </node>
    <node ...>
        <tag .../>
    </node>
</root>
```

I need to filter for particular "v" values and then use that to generate a list of lat, lon values using the parent node id as the unique id.

I can get the first node with the following

```
fence = soup.find(v="FenceLine")
prevnode = fence.find_parents("node")
print prevnode
```

How do I return a collection of parents only with children containing a specific attribute?

I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup after searching around, but I'm not sure it's the best for what I need?

Comment: BeautifulSoup should be fine, but if you want to validate the XML input to a schema it's probably better to use a validating XML parser than to parse with `BeautifulSoup` and then validate it yourself. What's the question? Without knowing why you're stuck I don't think it's really possible to say whether you'd get on better with a different parser.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited to be a bit clearer. Basically I can access the first item that matches, but unsure on the best way to return all that match in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want you can achieve your purpose by using standard "xml" library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_dict(value):
    root = ET.parse('a.xml')

    tmp={}

    for node in root.iterfind(".//tag[@v='{0}']/..".format(value)):
        tmp[node.get('id')] = (node.get('lat'),node.get('lon'))

    return tmp
```

The interesting part is:

```
root.iterfind(".//tag[@v='{0}']/..".format(value))
```

which returns an iterator which yields the parent tag of all the "tag" which have a "v" attribute matching "value".
If you prefer to get a list instead of an iterator you could use "findall" method instead of "iterfind".

For more information on "xml" library and the tricky syntax of "find" you can read the [official xml documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and the [xpath recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)